# Как импортировать переменные для последующей проверки(Подтверждение пароля)?

Tags: python, django

Я сделал форму регистрации, и теперь мне нужно сделать систему проверки 2-х паролей(Подтверждение пароля). Но я не знаю как мне импортировать в файл эти 2 переменные для проверки. Сейчас на данном этапе выводится ошибка о том, что такая переменная как password не найдена. Помогите...

```
forms.py:


from .models import registration 
from django.forms import ModelForm, TextInput

class registrationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = registration
        fields = ["first_name", "second_name", "email", "password", "password2", "date_of_birht"]
        widgets = {
            "first_name" : TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'id': 'inputName4'
                }),
            "second_name" : TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'id': 'inputSurname4'
                }),
            "email" : TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'id': 'inpuEmail1',
                'placeholder': 'name@example.com'
                }),
            "password" : TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'id': 'inputPass'
                }),
            "password2" : TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'id': 'inputPass1'
                }),
            "date_of_birht" : TextInput(attrs={
                'style': 'margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 30px; width: 300px; height: 45px; border-radius: 4px;" name="date',
                'id': 'localdate',
                'placeholder': 'День Месяц Год Пример: 12/12/2012',
                'pattern': '[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}'
                }),

            }

models.py:
        
        
from django.db import models

class registration(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField('Имя', max_length = 50)
    second_name = models.CharField('Фамилия', max_length = 50)
    email = models.CharField('Электронная почта', max_length = 50)
    password = models.CharField('Пароль', max_length = 32)
    password2 = models.CharField('Подтверждение пароля', max_length = 32)
    date_of_birht = models.DateField('Дата рождения')


views.py:


from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import registrationForm




def auth(request):
    return render(request, 'access/auth.html')


def reg(request):
    pass_error = ''
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = registrationForm(request.POST)
        if password == password2:
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            pass_error = 'Пароли не совпадают'  
            


    form = registrationForm()
    context = {
        'form' : form,
        'pass_error' : pass_error,
        
    }
    return render(request, 'access/reg.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. ты проверяешь `password == password2`, а в данном случае они являются аттрибутами формы
2. ты зря вообще во вью добавляешь проверку пароля, вынеси это в форму
3. ты зря в модель добавил поле повтор пароля, какой смысл его хранить? Просто добавь его в форму.
   в итоге твоя форма примет вид:

   class registrationForm(ModelForm):
   password2 = forms.CharField(label="Подтверждение пароля", widget=TextInput(attrs={
   'class': 'form-control',
   'id': 'inputPass1'
   })

   ```
    class Meta:
        model = registration
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            "first_name" : TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'id': 'inputName4'
                }),
            "second_name" : TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'id': 'inputSurname4'
                }),
            "email" : TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'id': 'inpuEmail1',
                'placeholder': 'name@example.com'
                }),
            "password" : TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'id': 'inputPass'
                }),
            "date_of_birht" : TextInput(attrs={
                'style': 'margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 30px; width: 300px; height: 45px; border-radius: 4px;" name="date',
                'id': 'localdate',
                'placeholder': 'День Месяц Год Пример: 12/12/2012',
                'pattern': '[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}'
                }),

            }

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        if cleaned_data.get('password') != cleaned_data.get('password2'):
            self.add_error('password2', 'Пароль и повтор пароля не совпадают')
        return cleaned_data
   ```

   и вью тебе нужно будет просто вызвать проверку валидации формы

   ```
    def reg(request):
        form = registrationForm(request.POST if request.POST else None)
        if request.method == "POST":
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('/')
        context = {
            'form' : form,
        }
        return render(request, 'access/reg.html', context)
   ```

pass_error уже будет не нужна, ты сможешь получить доступ к ошибке как и любой другой ошибке полей формы
`{{ form.password2.errors }}`
Такой способ будет лучше, так как в проверке внутри формы, она автоматически проверит на заполнение всех требуемых полей(которые ты не обозначил в модели как `blank=True`)

p.s.: Задолбался править. У начала формы постоянно съезжает форматирование, что это код.